# Errors when typsetting a table with odd columns and row alignments

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabulary

I am trying to typeset a table with "odd" (by my standards, please forgive my inexperience in these matters) columns and rows. Here is what I have thus far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color}

\title{MATH1111 NOTES}
\author{Philip (Micheal) Dykes}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    TRANSFORMATION & EFFECT ON GRAPH & CHANGES TO POINTS OF $f(x)$ \\ 
    \hline 
         \textbf{Vertical Shift} & & \\
        $y=f(x)+k$ & shift \textbf{down} $k$ units & $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,y+k)$ \\
        $y=f(x)-k$ & shift \textbf{up} $k$ units & $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,y-k)$ \\
    \hline
        \textbf{Horizontal Shift} & & \\
        $y=f(x-k)$ & shift \textbf{right} $k$ units & $(x,y) \rightarrow (x+k,y)$\\
        $y=f(x+k)$ & shift \textbf{left} $k$ units & $(x,y) \rightarrow (x-k,y)$\\
    \hline 
        \textbf{Vertical Stretch/Shrink} & &\\
        & vertical stretch $(a>1)$ & &\\
        & vertical shrink $(0<a<1)$ & &\\
        $y=a[f(x)]$ & $(x,y) \rightarrow (x,ay)$ &\\
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I keep getting error messages: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`, and am not sure what to do.

Thanks,
-MD

Comment: You've defined 3 columns but, e.g.,  `& vertical stretch $(a>1)$ & &` has 4 ones.

Answer (score 1):

There's one surplus `&` symbol in each of the following two rows:

```
    & vertical stretch $(a>1)$ & &\\
    & vertical shrink $(0<a<1)$ & &\\
```

Remove them and your code compiles.

Comment: However, I wish the $(x,y)\rightarrow(x,ay)$ to be in the right-most column.

Comment: @MichaelDykes - You still need to delete the third `&` symbol in each of the rows in order to get the code to compile without getting `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` messages. If you want to shift the `vertical ...` material one cell to the right, i.e., from the second to the third column, you must relocate the second `&` symbol in each of the two rows to the *left*, i.e., to before the `vertical ...` material.